# Bucle de redirección en admin (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS) Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Recién he instalado Magento 2 para hacer pruebas y revisar el código. Me he encontrado que al finalizar la instalación e intentar acceder al panel de administración (`/admin`) comienza una serie de re-direccionamientos en modo infinito.

He buscado información pero aun no encuentro nada, imagino que será por que la versión lleva apenas 1 mes de su lanzamiento.

[image: Captura de pantalla: re-direccionamiento infinito magento 2]

**Soluciones que no me funcionaron:**

- [Magento has a redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507584/magento-has-a-redirect-loop)
- [Magento 1.7.0.2 Too Many Redirects when installing magento with sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590017/magento-1-7-0-2-too-many-redirects-when-installing-magento-with-sample-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por favor no uses `localhost` como tu *hostname* , especialmente en Chrome. Es recomendable colocar un dominio propio. Revisa la [publicación de Alan](http://alankent.me/2015/04/25/use-of-localhost-when-installing-magento-2-quick-note/) para más detalles

Comment: @ Carlos-Munoz Thank you for translating!

Comment: Si, me ha funcionado y me ha quedado claro el error. Estaría perfecto que se añadieran detalles a esta repuesta para que no sólo se vea como una cita de link.